# Problema com função vector em C++

Tags: matriz, vector, c++14

Olá, estou tentando fazer uma calculadora de matrizes e a minha ideia seria que o usuário entrasse com o número de linhas, colunas e logo depois com os elementos da matriz, o problema é que quando vou escrever os elementos o programa dá erro de input stream, se alguém puder me ajudar.

## SOURCE

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int opc;
    int L = 0; //linha
    int C = 0; // coluna
    vector<vector<int>> mat1(L, std::vector<int>(C));
    vector<vector<int>> mat2(L, std::vector<int>(C));
    vector<vector<int>> matResp(L, std::vector<int>(C));

    cout << "1-Sum\n0-Exit\n";
    cin >> opc;

    system("cls");

    switch (opc)
    {
    case 1:
        //soma
        cout << "Enter with number of Lines:\n";
        cin >> L;
        cout << "Enter with number of Coluns:\n";
        cin >> C;

        cout << "Write the elements of Matrix A:\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {
                cin >> mat1[i][j];
            }
        }

        system("cls");

        cout << "Write the elements of Matrix B:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {
                cin >> mat2[i][j];
            }
        }

        system("cls");

        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {
                matResp[i][j] = mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            {
                cout << "[ " << matResp[L][C] << " ]";

                if (j == 2)
                    cout << endl;
            }
        }

        cout << endl;

        break;

    case 0:
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Wrong option";
        return main();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está criando os vetores antes de solicitar o tamanho, ou seja, com 0 linhas e 0 colunas.

Comment: hmm ok vou dar uma averiguada e assim que puder dou um respaldo

Comment: concegui achar o erro obrigado... a questão seria colocar um numero Max nas variáveis L e C e claro trocar elas para const

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin e Edson, podem melhorar esta resposta? Como está parece-me um comentário e não uma solução com exemplo da correção. Assim ficaria mais útil a quem possa ter o mesmo problema. Digam quando estiver editada para apagar o meu comment.

Comment: @Sergio tenha em mente o seguinte, ao invés de eu inicializar as variáveis C e L em 0 eu peso ao usuário digitar a ordem da matriz